# Magento 1.9.2 order ID duplicate entry if previously canceled

Tags: database, checkout, magento-1.9

I have a very annoying problem with **Magento 1.9.2** upgrade (previously was **1.7.0.2**)

I get time to time this error message in log file:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'OR1010702' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `sales_flat_order`...
```

It happens with every payment method, only if customer has already order before and his last order is Canceled or On Hold. It works fine when it's his first order or if previous one is Processing, Complete or Pending.

For exemple, a new customer goes through the checkout process, is redirected on Paypal or other payment solution page. If he uses his credit card correctly, no problem, but if he cancels his payment (the order is created and has status Canceled) he won't be able to process it again. He will stay on Magento checkout page and get javascript prompt error (something like: Payment issue, try latter)

Everything was fine with Magento 1.7 but with 1.9.2 upgrade I don't know what to do get order process working in any case.

If someone has and idea... Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer here: http://blog.adin.pro/2014-12-02/magento-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-000000254-for-key-unq_sales_flat_order_increment_id/

I had to override /app/code/local/Adin/Sales/Model/Resource/Sales/Quote.php in order to remove (int) in this line: $bind = array(':increment_id' => (int)$orderIncrementId);

Answer (score -1):

Although it's an old answer, I have found a solution which may help someone else in problem.
This problem happens when below conditions met

1. Customer has canceled previous order
2. Customer is trying again for a new order (with or without cookies cleared)
3. **Your setup has a custom invoice number which is not int**

Why the 3rd point above is bold? Because Magento already has solution to cover the first 2 conditions. Please check `function reserveOrderId()` in `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote.php` and `function isOrderIncrementIdUsed()` in `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Resource\Quote.php`.

To cover your custom invoice number which has chars within, you need to change below line

```
$bind      = array(':increment_id' => (int)$orderIncrementId);
```

with

```
$bind      = array(':increment_id' => $orderIncrementId);
```

in `function isOrderIncrementIdUsed()` in `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Resource\Quote.php`

**note: removal of (int)**

I hope you understood the problem now, but to be more precise, Magento tries to parse your invoice number 'OR1010702' into an int, which it can't. So this method returns false and hence no new invoice number is generated. Once you change the code to **not parse into int**, it is able to assign a new order id and it works fine.

**note: You should not touch any file inside `core` directory, rather copy the file with it's directory structure in `app\code\local` and do the changes there**